# QFileDialog::getOpenFileName doesn't working on MAC 10.10.5 Yosemite

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am using QFileDialog::getOpenFileName to open file dialog which give me the path of selected file.

Strange Behavior

This is working on

- MAC debug build
- Win debug build
- Win release build

Not Working on

- Mac Release build : returns empty string as filename

my code is

```
QString qResult = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(parent, qCaption, qDefaultPath, qFilter, &qSelectedFilter);
```

i checked for

1. parent : Valid pointer
2. pCation : valid string and caption is showing correctly
3. qDefaultPath : valid path and exists on machine, checked using  `QDir(qDefaultPath).exists()`
4. qFilter working fine
5. qSelectedFilter : seems fine

can anyone give me idea ? why is it happening ? or any alternative ?
please help this regards

Qt Version is 4.8.5

Comment: Try latest Qt 4.8 - 4.8.5 was release way before Mac OS X Yosemite. http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/26/qt-4-8-7-released/

Answer (score 2):

Does updating your Qt version a possible solution ? The most recent revision in 4.8 branch is 4.8.7. The [release note](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/26/qt-4-8-7-released/) for that version says:

> Better support for running Qt 4.8 applications on Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

and the [release note](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/04/24/qt-4-8-6-released/) for 4.8.6 says

> Better support for Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks

so there is a good chance your issue is fixed with the latest revision.

Comment: but  what could be the reason,it is working with debug build on Mac (Yosemite 10.10) ?